# Redis-commander won't load static files when run in iframe

Tags: node.js, iframe, nginx

I have the following problem:
There's a server with Redis on it. 
I want to be able to see Redis data and change it on my web-site. So I installed redis-commander on the server via npm. It usually listens to 8081 port. 
And in my front-end part I created a button "Redis manager", which showes view with the following html:

```
<iframe id="frame" src="{{redisUIUrl}}" />
```

redisUIUrl looks like: https://example.com/redis

there's NGINX between front-end and server, which is used for reverse-proxy purpose. - it makes proxy_pass to `oh_so_very_secret_syte.com:8081`

So, when we make this GET, we get views from redis-commander. Everything is fine. But in this views there are links to the static of type: `/css/default.css` - relative ones.

And the problem is that instead of loading static via the address `https://example.com/redis/css/default.css` it tries to load it via `https://example.com/css/default.css` and fails.

I don't really understand, what is the problem and how to deal with it. So, I am asking for your help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`/css/default.css` may be a relative URL, but it has an absolute path component. Which means that all references are relative to your server root.

If you require a path relative URL you need to drop the leading `/`.

```
css/default.css
```

will reference resources in the same directory as the current document.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are right, it helped. We loaded the static files. But .js files have some http request functions inside and their requests are not getting to example.com/redis as well. (but they should be). 
So, we either can try to change redis-commander js and html code, or stop using iframe
Probably, the best solution is not using iframe in this case.